# What would be preferred mark-up to add some Logos in a web page in HTML 5?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I need to add some logos in a web page

What would be preferred mark-up to add some Logos in a web page in HTML 5?

`<ul>` or HTML5 `<figure>`

[image]

Comment: What are the logos intended for? Is it something like "Compagnies using X?"

Answer (score 0):

I think both are valid, since both "this is a list of logo images" and "this is a figure consisting of some logo images" are defendable markup-wise and stylable.

Personally I would prefer the <ul> approach since I'd say it's more a list of logo's than a single figure.

Comment: Can't we put `<ul>` inside `<figure>`?

Comment: Because we can put multiple images inside `<figure>`

Comment: You can , since the specification (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element) does not require anything special from the content of a figure (similar to <div>).

Comment: But I think Figure is only for if we are using `<img>` and not for if use images through css `background`. Am i right?